# Microsoft.Usage : contains field that is of IDisposable type. Showing this error message

Tags: c#, sqlite, dispose, idisposable, sqlconnection

Showing this error message. I don't know how to fix the error. Please help with an example.

> Warning    1   CA2213 : Microsoft.Usage : 'StartUp' contains field 'StartUp.con' that is of IDisposable type: 'SQLiteConnection'. Change the Dispose method on 'StartUp' to call Dispose or Close on this field.   G:\Project\ DHQ Manager\Manager\StartUp.Designer.cs 15   Manager

Comment: You should probably read up on IDisposable and the Dispose pattern. Here are a couple of references: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw(v=vs.110).aspx; http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15360/Implementing-IDisposable-and-the-Dispose-Pattern-P.

Comment: Thanks Brother the Problem is solved